# Is it possible to re-use the image from another stage in Docker multi-stage builds?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to re-use the entire resulting image from another build stage?

The only application I'm aware of is using `COPY --from=some-stage` to copy files from another stage. I'm wondering if it's possible re-use the entire result of another stage, see an example below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS production
RUN /bin/bash install-my-app.sh

FROM production AS debug
RUN /bin/bash install-debug-tools.sh
```

This allows me to target the debug stage if I want to include the debug tools and configuration, while leaving the production steps untouched.

Comment: /!\ Warning: purely rhetoric question ahead /!\ Did you try ? What is the result ?

Comment: @Zeitounator Oh wow, I could swear this didn't work before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is perfectly possible as pointed out by @Zeitounator. To do it, just use the stage name as image name in `FROM` like so:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS production
RUN /bin/bash install-my-app.sh

FROM production AS debug
RUN /bin/bash install-debug-tools.sh
```